# Sorting dynamic table by certain field of that table

Tags: sorting, dynamic, abap

I'm having trouble with dynamic table sorting. Im reading a table via a dynamic field symbol. How can I sort this table by a certain field of that table (after the select). I know for a fact that this field is in the table, but since its dynamic I can't simply use "sort table by field".'

What are the alternatives?

Comment: `SORT itab BY ('FIELD').` doesn't work?

Comment: @andrecito That works yes, but it seems pretty quick and dirty to me.

Comment: If the internal table is created dynamically, then the sorting will be done dynamically too. As per [ABAP documentation on SORT](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abapsort_itab.htm), use `SORT itab BY (fieldname1) (fieldname2)...` or `SORT itab BY (itab_containing_list_of_fields)`

Comment: The bracket syntax as described by Sandra is the solution. If you are uncertain whether the column is contained, you can use an ASSIGN COMPONENT statement with attached sy-subrc validation to ensure it is really there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort

```
FIELD-SYMBOL <product_list> TYPE STANDARD TABLE.
```

by a single column with

```
CONSTANTS category TYPE char30 VALUE 'CATEGORY'.
SORT <product_list> BY (category).
```

and by multiple columns with

```
DATA(category_and_price) = VALUE abap_sortorder_tab( ( name = 'CATEGORY' ) 
                                                     ( name = 'PRICE'
                                                       descending = abap_true ) ).

SORT <product_list> BY (category_and_price).
```

as described in the [ABAP Keyword Documentation article `SORT itab`](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abapsort_itab.htm).